# India to UK bank transfers

Tags: united-kingdom, india, gift-tax, transfer

Is a UK passport holder with an Indian bank account in Kolkata, allowed to transfer money to their son's UK bank account as a gift. He is a UK passport holder.

Thank you

Comment: So both you and your son are UK tax resident?